# Where do you configure log4j settings in jboss6

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss5.x, jboss6.x

jboss-6.0.0.Final doesn't seem to have jboss-log4j.xml which was used to configure log4j settings in jboss5 (i.e. under server/default/conf/jboss-log4j.xml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the name and location changed since release 6:

> In the releases 4.x and 5.x it's
>   located
>   here:JBoss_HOME\server\default\conf\jboss-log4j.xml
>
> Since the release 6.0.0 M1 it's
>   located in the deploy folder:
>   JBOSS_HOME\server\default\deploy\jboss-logging.xml

Source: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/251-jboss-log4j-configuration.html

Comment: It must be noted that JBoss AS 6 doesn't use log4j anymore cause it proved to be vulnerable to deadlocks and performance problems. jboss-logging.xml is configuration for custom JBoss logging framework. I would suggest switching apps from log4j to slf4j and using slf4j-jboss-logging.jar adapter.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using axis2.war the log4j.properties is there in axis2.war/WEB-INF/classes so what you do set the log4j.properties in a classpath.