# log4j Logger messages are not displayed on JBoss webapp

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, jboss6.x

I use Jboss 6 and my

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
```

displays nothing

Tried adding log4 to my project, removing it, placing a log4j file on my main/resources folder, placing no log4j file and no results.

Only System.Out seems to work, but it doesn't provide all the information I would like to see

I even see Hibernate log working but not mine

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my logging does work. Hibernate logging is controlled by the jboss logging settings.

My logging began to work as soon as I placed the log4j on right next to the classes folder, and placing log4j jar with the project

Answer (score 1):

JBoss AS 6 doesn't use log4j by default anymore.
Cause log4j 1.2.x proved to be [vulnerable to deadlocks and performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537870/production-settings-file-for-log4j/13144054).

Google suggests plenty of links on using log4j with JBoss AS 6:

[Where do you configure log4j settings in jboss6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382224/where-do-you-configure-log4j-settings-in-jboss6)

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/325-using-log4j-with-jboss-6.html

http://community.jboss.org/thread/154993

http://community.jboss.org/thread/160796

http://community.jboss.org/thread/159862

But I would suggest switching apps from log4j to [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), using `jboss-6.0.0.Final/common/lib/slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar` adapter and having all logging configuration in single [jboss-logging.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382224/where-do-you-configure-log4j-settings-in-jboss6).