# JBoss AS 6 - the log4j configuration

Tags: java, configuration, log4j, jboss6.x

I have migrated from `JBoss 4.2.3` to `JBoss AS 6`. On the `JBoss 4.2.3` I had configured `log4j` to output some logs in different files using `log4j.properties`. The current logging (on JBoss AS 6) doesn't output anything but the default `server.log` and `boot.log`. Please help me find why I don't get the other logs.

Here is my project structure:

```
/src
 `--log4j.properties
/META-INF
 `--jboss-deployment-structure.xml
/lib (added to classpath)
 `--log4j.jar
```

I added the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` after the migration due to reading I found on that issue. Unfortunately this doesn't worked for me. Here are the configurations:

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**log4j.properties**

```
# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

# Set the enterprise logger category to FATAL and its only appender to CONSOLE.
#log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.enterprise=FATAL, CONSOLE

# Categories
log4j.category.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%F->%M() line%L] %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM:ss} - %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding=ISO-8859-1

# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/cache.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Encoding=ISO-8859-1

# AspectJ time logger
log4j.logger.TimeLog=DEBUG, timeLog, CONSOLE
log4j.additivity.TimeLog=false

log4j.appender.timeLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.timeLog.File=${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/time.log
log4j.appender.timeLog.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.timeLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.timeLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.timeLog.Encoding=ISO-8859-1
```

The time logger is my custom logger that is why it has a bit different configuration.

**P.S.** And please don't tell me that my mistake is that I am using version 6 of JBoss.

Comment: See the answer mentioned here. You have to add the log4j as a module http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584787/using-log4j-with-jboss-7-1

Comment: In this answer you are not adding the log4j as a module but excluding it from load queue from the server(as I see it) so the default config will not be loaded. As you can see I've added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml content in my question. In there I have mentioned the module log4j and this didn't work for me.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, log4j should be configured in the /deploy/jboss-logging.xml file, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382224/where-do-you-configure-log4j-settings-in-jboss6